# How to select all attributes (*) with distinct values in a particular column(s)?

Tags: sql

Here is link to the w3school database for learners:

[W3School Database](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_distinct)

If we execute the following query:

`SELECT DISTINCT city FROM Customers`

it returns us a list of different City attributes from the table.

What to do if we want to get all the rows like that we get from `SELECT * FROM Customers` query, with unique value for City attribute in each row.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result out of it into the question.

Comment: How do you expect to aggregate the data for a city?

Comment: You can't. DISTINCT will Always work on the entire list of columns in the SELECT clause.

Comment: May be you need `Group By` contruction

Comment: You have to group result by city, but you have to know how to deal with other columns

Comment: As the table contains a set of rows for a city your options are  an aggregation of the rows of the set, adding more criteria to specify which row of the set to select, selecting a random row from the set.

Answer (score 0):

**DISTINCT** when used with multiple columns, is applied for all the columns together. So, the set of values of all columns is considered and not just one column.

If you want to have distinct values, then **concatenate all the columns**, which will make it distinct.

Or, you could group the rows using **GROUP BY**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:
(change `PK` field to your `Customers` Table primary key or index like `Id`)

In SQL Server (and standard SQL)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY PK) rn
    FROM
        Customers ) Dt
WHERE
    (rn = 1)
```

In MySQL

```
SELECT 
    * 
FORM (
    SELECT 
        a.City, a.PK, count(*) as rn 
    FROM 
        Customers a
        JOIN 
        Customers b ON a.City = b.City AND a.PK >= b.PK
    GROUP BY a.City, a.PK ) As DT
WHERE (rn = 1)
```

This query -I hope - will return your Cities distinctly and also shows other columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select all values from `customers` table, where `city` is unique. So, logically, I came with such query:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `city` in (SELECT DISTINCT `city` FROM `customers`)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use GROUP BY clause for getting distinct values in a particular column. Consider the following table - 'contact':

```
+---------+------+---------+
| id      | name | city    |
+---------+------+---------+
| 1       | ABC  | Chennai |
+---------+------+---------+
| 2       | PQR  | Chennai |
+---------+------+---------+
| 3       | XYZ  | Mumbai  |
+---------+------+---------+
```

To select all columns with distinct values in City attribute, use the following query:

SELECT *
FROM contact
GROUP BY city;

This will give you the output as follows:

```
+---------+------+---------+
| id      | name | city    |
+---------+------+---------+
| 1       | ABC  | Chennai |
+---------+------+---------+
| 3       | XYZ  | Mumbai  |
+---------+------+---------+
```

Comment: That is invalid SQL and any self-respecting DBMS will reject it.